# How to recognize latest sequence ID from the GD project dataset?

Tags: hash, sequence, gooddata

How can I dynamically refer the latest sequence ID from the GD project dataset when calling sequence function in ETL to connect that project?

If intending to dynamically determine from which number to restart incrementing the sequence, how should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m afraid there is not any dynamic function to determine the latest sequence ID in a meaning of your question, but it is always possible to save this information somewhere on persistent storage on the ETL level and read it when the next ETL triggers. If the sequence is also being uploaded to the GD project as a fact, you can use the “SELECT MAX(FactName)” function.

Sincerely
Filip